# SharePoint Search: Exclude lists and listitems from search results

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, search, configuration

I'm very new to MOSS 2007 search and just started playing around with the configuration. At the moment the index contains nearly everything a site has to offer.

After testing the search on my publishing portal, I realized that many of the search results are not very useful for the users. E.g. the search results include entries to the explorer view of lists and libraries or lists and libraries and their items which shouldn't appear in the results at all, like pictures and graphics which are used for page design.

I know that I can select the content which will be added to the index by defining crawl rules so certain items can be included or excluded.

What I want to achieve is to exclude all list and list items from the search results regardless of where they are located within a publishing site or one of its sub sites. In a second step I want to include only certain lists and libraries into the index.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any adequate rules to realize that in a smart way without enumerating every single list or library I want to exclude.

So how does a rule have to look like to match every list, library and item.

Perhaps some MOSS 2007 search experts can give me some tips or links where I can find some more information on that problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to create Search Scopes. You can create them globally though the Shared Service Provider configuration or at the Site Collection level through Site Settings.

Check out: [Creating and Exposing Search Scopes in SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428856.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Create search scopes using `ContentType` and `ContentClass` to limit the results to what you desire.

[example](http://blog.3i-solutions.nl/2008/01/creating-search-scopes-based-on.html)

Be warned that for search scopes using ContentType, pages that are set to be the "Welcome Page" for the site lose their content type for the search index and are classed as having a content class of a web site.

Answer (score 2):

You can also exclude a specific list using the setting List Settings -> List Advanced Settings -> Allow items from this list to appear in search results

Answer (score -1):

[How to exclude results from people search with Active Directory](http://thingsnowhere.blogspot.com/2009/07/sharepoint-how-to-exclude-results-from.html) - this link may help. If you have more questions email me and I will try to answer them here.